# selenium-2 Webdriver xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

Code screenshot :

[image]

Here i want to locate the **Available Balance** label via the class `FORM_NEW_ACCOUNT`

how to write selenium xpath?

I have tried some scenarios nothing works, among those one is here

```
//div[contains(@class,'FORM_NEW_ACCOUNT')]//label[text()='Available Balance']
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZnuIirVvw8

Comment: Have you tried this //div[contains(@class,'FORM_NEW_ACCOUNT')]//label[contains(text(),'Available Balance')]

Comment: Please provide URL

Answer (score 0):

There might be some spaces with **Available Balance** label so `label[text()='Available Balance']` won't work in this case. You can use below xpath to locate:

```
//table[@class='x-table-layout']//label[contains(.,'Available Balance')]
```

OR

```
//div[contains(@class,'FORM_NEW_ACCOUNT')]//label[contains(.,'Available Balance')]
```

Its always recommended to use CSS Selector instead of Xpath.

```
div.Form_NEW_ACCOUNT table.x-table-layout label.x-form-item.label
```

It seems all the Id's are dynamic in your page so try using some other unique attributes.